# Renaming columns in multiple dataframes in R with loops

Tags: r, loops

I am new to loops in r. I have been trying to write this as a loop but am not able to get the desired result

```r
outage_0 <- rename(outage_0,sd_out_0 = sd_out,
                   out_0 = out)
outage_1 <- rename(outage_1,sd_out_1 = sd_out,
                   out_1 = out)
outage_2 <- rename(outage_2,sd_out_2 = sd_out,
                   out_2 = out)
outage_3 <- rename(outage_3,sd_out_3 = sd_out,
                   out_3 = out)
outage_4 <- rename(outage_4,sd_out_4 = sd_out,
                   out_4 = out)
outage_5 <- rename(outage_5,sd_out_5 = sd_out,
                   out_5 = out)
outage_6 <- rename(outage_6,sd_out_6 = sd_out,
                   out_6 = out)
```

Basically I am trying to rename the same columns in each dataframe and want it to be reflected in the original dataframe. Storing all dataframes in a list did not work.

Comment: Is `outage_6` supposed to be renamed using `outage_7` ? The numbers match in the other examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

We could get all the datasets in a `list` and then `rename` at once, store in a list

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^outage_\\d+')) %>%
   imap(~ .x %>%
            rename(!! str_replace(.y, 'outage', 'sd_out') := sd_out))
```

If we want to modify the original objects, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
for(i in 0:6)
{
obj <- paste0('outage_', i)
tmp <- get(obj)
tmp <- tmp %>%
      rename(!! paste0('sd_out_', i) := sd_out)
assign(obj, tmp)
}
```